# Flash storage: How do I know the remaining writing cycles without relying on SMART?

Tags: data-storage

Flash storage such as SSD has a SMART system like HDDs.

But  USB sticks and SD cards lack that.

Optical storage has error/quality scanning that can predict failures early, while error correction is still able to cope.

Is such a quality scan or any other way able to measure the approximate remaining writing cycles for flash transistors?

Comment: No, that why you have the Flash controller. Many MCU's for example have a boot block with very low write numbers (in the low thousands).    http://www.esacademy.com/en/library/technical-articles-and-documents/8051-programming/using-flash-memory-in-embedded-applications.html  ...older but may help.

Comment: Not  a chance.   The technology changes faster than the lifetimes, so tested accurate 'wear' indications don't catch up.   Estimates as given by manufacturers are available, but like SMART they won't be perfect.